# Which unit testing frameworks have ASP.NET MVC extensions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, frameworks

I normally use MSpec and the fantastic [Machine.Specifications.Mvc extensions](http://jamesbroo.me/introducing-machinespecificationsmvc/), with extensions as `ShouldBeAView()`, `ShouldBeARedirect()`, `ShouldHaveModelOfType<T>()`.

But I'll be writing a project for a client and since BDD and MSpec are not everyone's cup of tea and they'll be updating the code in the future I wanted to look at alternatives.

Just to compile a list of which possible Unit Testing Framework candidates for a coming ASP.NET MVC (3) project, which frameworks/libraries expose similar unit testing extensions for MVC?

These extensions are easy to write, I know, but I want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Try here:

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper